# Most efficient Django query to return results spanning multiple tables

Tags: python, django

I am trying to do a pretty complex query in Django in the most efficient way and I am not sure how to get started. I have these models (this is a simplified version)

```
class Status(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Event(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class EventItem(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    rev1 = models.ForeignKey(Status, related_name='rev1', blank=True, null=True)
    rev2 = models.ForeignKey(Status, related_name='rev2', blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField()
```

I want to create a query that will result in a list of Users that have the most events in which all their dependent EventItems have `rev1` and `rev2` are not blank or nulland `active = True`.

I know I could do this by iterating through the list of users and then checking all their events for the matching `rev1`, `rev2`, and `active` criteria and then return those events, but this is heavy on the database. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to create a query that will result in a list of Users that have the most events in which all their dependent EventItems have rev1 and rev2 are not blank or null and active = True.

First, you want `Event` objects which always have this type of `EventItem`.

```
events = Event.objects.filter(active=True)
events = events.exclude(eventitem__rev1__isnull=True)
events = events.exclude(eventitem__rev1='')
events = events.exclude(eventitem__rev2__isnull=True)
events = events.exclude(eventitem__rev2='')
```

Also, you didn't specify if you wanted to deal with `Event` objects that have no `EventItem`. You can filter those out with:

```
events = events.exclude(eventitem__isnull=True)
```

Note that `events` may contain plenty of duplicates. You can throw in an `events.distinct()` if you like, but should only do that if you need it human-readable.

Once you have those, you can now extract the `User` objects that you want:

```
users = User.objects.filter(event__in=events)
```

Note that on certain database backends, *ahem* MySQL *ahem*, you may find that the `.filter(field__in=QuerySet)` pattern is [really slow](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in). For that case, the code should be:

```
users = User.objects.filter(event__in=list(events.values_list('pk', flat=True)))
```

You may then order things by the number of `Event` objects attached:

```
from django.db.models import Count
active_users = users.annotate(num_events=Count('event')).order_by('-num_events')
```

Answer (score 6):

Your model is broken, but this should sum up what you were doing in a cleaner way.

```
class Status(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    events = models.ManyToManyField('Event')

class Event(models.Model):
    rev1 = models.ForeignKey(Status, related_name='rev1', blank=True, null=True)
    rev2 = models.ForeignKey(Status, related_name='rev2', blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField()
```

And the query

`User.objects.filter(events__active=True).exclude(Q(events__rev1=None)|Q(events__rev2=None)).annotate(num_events=Count('events')).order_by('-num_events')`

This will return a list of users, sorted by the number of events in their set.

For more information check out [Many-To-Many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) fields.

Comment: Thanks, Roman, but it doesn't really match my question - I am not using a `ManyToMany` field - any idea how I do things with my current model. I did originally forget the 'event` field in the `EventItem` but I added that. Thanks!

Comment: This is an excellent answer to the question that starts of with "What is the best way to plan my models for ... types of queries".

Unfortunately @JonoBacon wasn't asking this question. Perhaps next time?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
EventItem.objects.exclude(rev1=None).exclude(rev2=None).filter(active=True).values_list('event__user', flat=True)
```

That will give you a flat list of user ids, where the frequency of each id is how many EventItem objects that user has.

You may be able to do better, and integrate this into a query using `.annotate()`, but I'm not sure how to right now.